# Splitting a string on dot (.) except if it appears in a fraction using regex in Java

Tags: java, regex

As the title says, I want to split a string using java regex based on dot but only if the dot appears in between alphabets.

Lets say the string is:

```
System.out.println(5.55);
```

I need output as

```
System
out
println(5.55);
```

Comment: Hint: String.split() accepts regex, and `\D` is any non-numerical literal

Comment: This is pretty simple to achieve. You shouldn't need help if you look at the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Yeah its simple... but i was a bit confused with lookahead and lookbehind functionality. Have already read the documentation b4 asking the question. Anyways thanks for ur comment :)

Comment: You should use a Java parser if you want to do serious processing of source code. Regex gives you a fast prototype, but it will never develop into a full solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use lookahead and lookbehind like this

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString("System.out.println(5.55);".split("(?<=\\D)\\.(?=\\D)")));
```

For further reference what they actually do you could read through [this](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Answer (score 2):

A lookbehind and lookahead for letters is probably what you want.  [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hJ1nQ7/1)

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])\.(?=[a-zA-Z])

String content = "asdf.qweflkjasdf.qweflasdfasfd55.523";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?<=[a-zA-Z])\\.(?=[a-zA-Z])");           
System.out.println(p.matcher(content).replaceAll("\n"));

OUTPUT:
asdf
qweflkjasdf
qweflasdfasfd55.523
```